# How to paraphrase a 3 step process in one sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, phrase-requests, american-english

Good day everyone,

I have the following sentence:

> Receive qualified developers, screen by more experienced developers.

I want to ensure that the meaning is well understood.
This sentence is simply targeting hiring managers, and the below hiring steps are supposed to translate into the above sentence.

- You submit a request to hire a developer.
- A Senior Developer evaluates our available members whose
  qualifications matches your requirements.
- The Senior Developer links you with the member selected.

I want to double check that this sentence alone is well understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence is missing the third part completely, and I largely misunderstood it. I suggest using a paraphrase of your explanation:

> When you submit a request to hire a developer, a Senior Developer will evaluate our available members whose qualifications match your requirements and link you to them.

Answer (score 3):

1. You wouldn't *receive developers*. (I'm picturing a programmer in a shipping crate.) You might receive *resumes* or *contact information*, or you might be *connected* to developers.
2. These developers have been screened *by* other developers.

You might say:

> Connect with qualified developers who have been screened by our Senior Developers.